# UIActivityview indicator help?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I would like the UIActivityindicator to spin as long as a method isn't finshed loading like one of my methods parses data from a website so I would uiactivity indicator to spin as long as the method isn't finished doing its job.

thanks,

Tushar Chutani

Answer (score 0):

the obvious answer is   [activityView startAnimating]

however i suspect you are running a synchronous retrieval of the data and you are not getting back control of the UI until you have finished your method.

if that is so you will need to run your method in the background and then do the UI updates on the main thread.

post some code .....